# セル内で ” (ダブルクォート) を文字のまま表示する方法

Tags: google-spreadsheet

まず、参照したいセルをA1として、A1に「山田太郎」と入力すると
="名前は"&A1&"です"
なら、セルは「名前は山田太郎です」と表示してくれるのですが、
「"name": "山田太郎",」と表示しようとして、
=""name":""&A1&"","と入力すると、当たり前ですがエラーが出ます。

「"name": "山田太郎",」という文字列をセルに出力するにはどうすればいいですか？

追記：
A1セルに「山田太郎」と入力
A1セルに書かれた内容を参照し、B1セルに「"name": "山田太郎",」と表示したいです。
つまり、A1セルに書かれた内容が「佐藤祐樹」に変更された場合、B1セルが「"name": "佐藤祐樹",」となるような方法です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 単なる意見ですが、Excel方眼紙を作ってしまうのと同根の、ツールの主要な用途を逸脱した考え方のように見えます。ツールに向いていない使い方で何もかもまとめて1度にやろうとするのは考え直した方が良いのでは？

Answer (score 1):

```
="""name"":"""&A1&""","
```

下記参考資料はエクセルですが、Googleスプレッドシートでも同じようにいけました。

[エクセル：式の中で「"（ダブルクォート）」を文字として入力する](https://at.sachi-web.com/excel_text_doublequote.html)

Answer (score 0):

google-spreadsheetで, ダブルクォーテーションマーク(`"`)を文字列の中で使うには 2つ続けて記述します。
`hello "world"` ならば, `="hello ""world"""` のように

なので次のように記述します

```
="""name"":"""&A1&""""
```

---

追記

最後にカンマ付けるようなので訂正

```
="""name"":"""&A1&""","
```